# umbraco mvc form model validation markup not showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, validation, umbraco

Running Umbraco 6.05, I have a custom model class with Data Annotations like:

[Required, StringLength(100), DataType(DataType.EmailAddress), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]

and I pass the model to the view like so:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<test.local.Models.ContactForm>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>ContactForm</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        ...

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

But when it renders, the "data-val" attributes are missing, though interestingly the DataType EmailAddress/MultiLine work fine by inserting 'type="email"' and creating a 'textarea' appropriately.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Can you add code for your model definition?

Answer (score 1):

Answer found here:

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/36898-Enable-unobtrusive-validation-for-mvc-forms

Turn on client side validation in your web.config

Comment: both the root level one and the one in the views folder